# Add multiple Time lines in project center

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, project-server

We are working on a project server, and my manager asked me to add a new timeline for the project center for the projects!

Is it possible to add multiple timelines in project server 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unfortunately,** you can't add `multiple timelines` in Project Server 2013.

The `Multiple TimeLine` is introduced in Project Server 2016.

[image]

For more details, check

- [Project Server 2016: New and deprecated features compared to Project Server 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/29/simply-whats-new-and-deprecated-features-in-project-server-2016/)
- [What’re new features in Project Server 2016 compared to Project Server 2013?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37814.project-server-2016-new-and-deprecated-features-compared-to-project-server-2013.aspx)

Comment: No workarounds?

Comment: No, it's by design in PS 2013! Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you!